# Unity 2d Jump and run Enemy flip 180 on the x postion when im right or left

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Unity 2d Jump and run Enemy flip 180 on the x postion when im right or left to him.
It shoud be an easy code but i dont know how i afford that.

Do i Need an anim controller for that ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're asking. Can you be more descriptive of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Okay now at the moment the enmy is facing only in one direction the enemy is follow me till he hit me and when im right to him or left he doesnt flip so he is running backwards to me and i wanna know how to code that.       so maybe with the transform.LookAt(target);         but he still doesnt flip. Thansk